# Iniciar aplicação por meio do windows service

Tags: c#

É possivel iniciar uma aplicação .exe ao iniciar Windows Service c#?

Algo do Tipo:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

        Process.Start(@"C:\service.exe");
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }
```

Obrigado!

Comment: seja mais   claro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não pode iniciar uma aplicativo interativo desktop a partir de um serviço do Windows. Isso mudou a partir do Windows Vista.

Você pode até executar **`Process.Start(@"C:\service.exe");`**, mas o aplicativo irá executar em forma de processo (background), e não como aplicativo da área de trabalho. Isso se deve ao novo controle de conta de usuário (UAC).

Comment: Boa. Não fazia ideia disso.

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado!